# How to terminate a fragment used within a drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, drawer

I have a drawer which has 3 items in the menu that instantiate 3 fragments:A  B  C

I start by default with A. Then I switch from the drawer menu on B.

The user decides that B is taking too long and he brings up the drawer menu to switch back to A or to C. My B code which is manipulating a listview will move to A or C only when the B task will be completed.

What is the way to move between fragments? I think I should terminate the current fragment.

The code which is handling the fragment is the following:

```
   private void selectItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment;

        if(position == 9) return;
        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mTools[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        Bundle args;

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                fragment = new AFragment();
                args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(AFragment.POSITION, position);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new BFragment();
                args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(BFragment.POSITION, position);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new CFragment();
                args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(CFragment.POSITION, position);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                break;
            default:
                fragment = new AFragment();
                args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(AFragment.POSITION, position);
                fragment.setArguments(args);

        }
        // update the main content by replacing fragments



        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(id.content_frame, fragment).commit();


    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "terminate"? As soon as you click on a separate list position, you lose the reference to the current Fragment for a new one, then it gets replaced in the Activity

Comment: it is not the case. When I select B in the drawer the task could tke 15-30 sec. I could decide to force the user to terminate the B task. The user could be impatient and seeing that it is taking too much time, he could decide to re-open the drawer to switch to C. If he does that my code will wait to terminate B to switch to C. Is there a way to force to finish the fragment B to switch to C?

Comment: Are you referring to some AsyncTask taking a long time?

Comment: No. we had a discussion about it in a separate thread. I try to discover IP devices and add them in a listview. this task is taking 15-30sec.

Comment: Right. Still don't know how/what you mean by "terminate". What is the process that would require termination? Do you know how you would do that in code? As I said, as soon as you hit `fragment = new OtherFragment()`, then you no longer have access to terminate anything

Comment: ok.thanks! so i'll add a stop button :)